# Error in evaluating a For loop

Tags: plotting, evaluation

I defined an integral function and for solve it, I want to calculate it for some numbers and then plot its behavior. So I put the function in a For loop to automate this procedure and then plot the data. but when I call the function I see these Errors:

```
In[1]:= g[x_,x0_,v0_]:=Integrate[1/Sqrt[v0^2+Integrate[19.6,{s,x0,x}]],{u,x0,x}];

In[2]:= t[0]=0;deltat[T_,n_]:=Do[t[i]=t[i-1]+T/n,{i,n}]

In[3]:= displ[n_,x0_,v0_]:=For[i=1;t[0]=0;x[0]=x0,i<=n,i++,y=FindRoot[g[x,x0,v0]==t[i],
{x,x[i-1]},MaxIterations->50];x[i]=x/.y;]

In[4]:= deltat[5,20]; displ[20,0.001,0.001];
During evaluation of In[4]:= FindRoot::srect: Value x[0.] in search specification {x,x[i-1]} is not a number or array of numbers.
During evaluation of In[4]:= FindRoot::srect: Value x[0.] in search specification {x,x[i-1]} is not a number or array of numbers.
During evaluation of In[4]:= FindRoot::srect: Value x[0.] in search specification {x,x[i-1]} is not a number or array of numbers.
During evaluation of In[4]:= General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::srect will be suppressed during this calculation.
During evaluation of In[4]:= ReplaceAll::reps: {FindRoot[g[x,0.001,0.001]==t[i],{x,x[i-1]},MaxIterations->50]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.
During evaluation of In[4]:= ReplaceAll::reps: {FindRoot[g[x,0.001,0.001]==t[i],{x,x[i-1]},MaxIterations->50]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.
During evaluation of In[4]:= ReplaceAll::reps: {FindRoot[g[x,0.001,0.001]==t[i],{x,x[i-1]},MaxIterations->50]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.
During evaluation of In[4]:= General::stop: Further output of ReplaceAll::reps will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program is quite complicated, but it is not very difficult to find a much simpler example that shows the same problem. Please clear all variables before trying this.

**Example 1.**

```
w[0]=2;
FindRoot[3-w,{w,w[0]}]
```

This produces exactly the error you describe.

**Example 2.**

```
w[0]=2;
FindRoot[3-q,{q,w[0]}]
```

This works and finds `{q->3.}`.

So the problem in Example 1 arises because there is a conflict: The same symbol `w` is used in `FindRoot` both as the unknown variable and in the initial condition. Perhaps as a quick solution, you can simply accept that and choose another variable name in your `FindRoot` that has no conflict?

(If you want to understand this more in detail, see the documentation of `FindRoot`, and read about `Block` and `HoldAll` and so on.)